# Current state of Google bot ajax indexing

Tags: jquery, ajax, googlebot

what's the current status of Google bot indexing ajax sites? I have links displaying some list:

mysite.com/list#key=value&foo=bar

Content is loaded dynamic by jQuery just after page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // load content to div by $.ajax() request
});
```

Do Google crawls it and gets the loaded content or do I have to do some evil magick tricks shown here: http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

I fetched site as Google Bot but html is without ajax content :(

Comment: Well... if Google tells you how make your Ajax pages crawlable it probably means you have to do so.

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine how your AJAX-enabled site is doing with Google's crawlers is to wait until it's crawled and then find it in the Google search results and then view the site preview:

[image]

The screenshot you see is what Google saved when crawling. So if you have AJAX-stuff happening on your page and they are showing up properly in that screenshot, then you can probably assume that Google is crawling and correctly indexing those AJAX-enabled pages.